# Proof of L'Hospital rule

Tags: real-analysis, limits

So I've stumbled upon a proof of L'Hospital rule in my real analysis textbox that I can't seem to understand. Here goes:

$$ \text{Let } f,g:[a, b) \to \mathbb{R} \text{ be functions that satisfy the following conditions: }$$
$$\text{1. } f \text{ and } g \text{ are continuous on the interval } [a, b) $$
$$\text{2. } f \text{ and } g \text{ are differentiable on the interval } (a, b) \text{ where } g'(x) \neq 0 \quad (\forall x\in(a, b))  $$
$$\text{3. } f(a) = g(a) = 0 $$

$$ \text{If } \lim_{x \to a^+}{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}} \text{ exists, then } \lim_{x \to a^+}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}} \text{ exists and } \lim_{x \to a^+}{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}} = \lim_{x \to a^+}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}} $$

Proof.

$$ \text{Let } x \in (a, b) \text{ be arbitrary.} $$
$$ \text{Then the functions } f \text{ and } g \text{ satisfy the conditions of Cauchy's theorem on the interval } [a, x] \\ \text{Therefore } \exists \delta = \delta(x) \in (a, x) \text{ such that: }\\ \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{g(x) - g(a)} = \frac{f'(\delta(x))}{g'(\delta(x))} $$

$$ \text{Since } f(a) = g(a) = 0 \text{ we have: } \\ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(\delta(x))}{f'(\delta(x))}$$

$$ \text{Let } \lim_{x \to a^+}{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}} = L \text{. Since } a < \delta(x) < x \text{ , by the squeeze theorem we have } \lim_{x \to a^+}{\delta(x)} = a \\ \text{Since } \delta(x) > a (\forall x \in (a, b)) \text{ we know that } \lim_{x \to a^+}{\frac{f'(\delta(x))}{g'(\delta(x))}} \text{ exists and let: } \\ \lim_{x \to a^+}{\frac{f'(\delta(x))}{g'(\delta(x))}} = L $$

$$ \text{Now, since } \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(\delta(x))}{g'(\delta(x))} \text{ , we get } \lim_{x \to a^+}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}} =  \lim_{x \to a^+}{\frac{f'(\delta(x))}{g'(\delta(x))}} = L = \lim_{x \to a^+}{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}} $$

Now, if I were to pretend to understand how they applied Cauchy's theorem then I would understand the entire proof. What I'm finding hard to understand is the whole notation 
$$ \delta = \delta(x)$$
What does that mean? Is delta a constant? If so then how can I later evaluate its limit (via squeeze theorem) to be equal to a. If it's not a constant, how come it came from Cauchy's theorem which states that there exists a constant in a given interval for which those rules apply.

I'm so confused about this that I'm not even sure how to properly ask this question.

Comment: https://youtu.be/kfF40MiS7zA

Comment: $\delta$ is not a constant but rather depends on interval $[a, x] $ and hence depends on $x $. Cauchy's theorem is being applied not on a fixed interval but rather on a varying interval $[a,x]$.

Comment: It's **l'Hôpital's rule**, even though l'Hôpital means Hospital in French, the rule was named after the French mathematician Guillaume de l'Hôpital.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I'll keep that in mind

Comment: I see this very often that people call this L'Hospital's rule and according to the internet this is somewhat accepted as well. I'm surprised to learn that. To me saying L'Hospital's rule doesn't make any sense as the "L' " is French (and shouldn't be capital) and "Hospital" is English. Like make up your mind people! :) Anyway, that concludes my rant.

Comment: @Mathematician42: Actually, l'Hôpital is the *modern* French spelling of what used to be spelled l'Hospital when the guy himself lived. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_de_l%27H%C3%B4pital#/media/File:L%27Hospital_-_Analyse_des_infiniment_petits_pour_l%27intelligence_des_lignes_courbes,_1715_-_1425244.jpg), for example.

Comment: If the $\delta$ from Cauchy's theorem were a constant, it would be a nice project to compute it once and for all. Alas, it *cannot* be a global constant, but by necessity depends on the function(s) considered and the interval end points. Within this proof of l'Hôpital, $f$ ad $g$ amd $a$ are fixed - but $x$ varies and hence so does $\delta$, which makes it a function of $x$. And this dependency can be expressed notationally by writing it explicitly as a function of $x$, i.e., $\delta(x)$.

Comment: @HansLundmark : I retract my rant and I'll be fine with it then :) I certainly hope the "s" in "Hospital" was not pronounced in old French, that would shatter my world.

Comment: @Mathematician42: Well, it certainly was pronounced if you go back in time far enough, but as far as I can tell, it had already been silent for a long time in l'Hôpital's days. (For example, see the fifth item in the list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_French#Table_of_vowel_outcomes).)

Comment: @HansLundmark : You came very close to shattering my world!

Comment: @Mathematician42: Sorry about that! ;-)

Comment: Could you guys please take this somewhere else? I'm not sure how to close the thread and the notifications are pretty annoying.